# MySQL select - get specified column first, then all other columns (asterisk) - error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL (v.5.6) table with lots of columns and want to select a specified column as first column - and then all other columns - to view the data.

```
select *, column from table; --is allowed
select column, * from table; --MySQL error 1064
```

Why? Workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do 1 + all *other*, but you can do 1 + all of them by using `table.*`

```
SELECT col1, t.* FROM table t
```

This will select col1 twice, but otherwise works fine.

Comment: This trick also works on Oracle (not surprising, since both products come from the same company).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen although it did work before Oracle bought MySQL </nitpick> :)

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because it does!

The 'Workaround' is to specify all columns explicitly,  which really is best-practice anyway.

Using Select * in all but trivial applications is asking for problems in the future.